# I want to make a time selection in the timeout command, but I don’t understand how

Tags: discord, bots, timeout, disnake

I don’t understand how to make a choice of time, from the word in general

````py
@commands.slash_command(name='timeout', description='Замутить пользователя')
        async def command_timeout(self, interaction, member: disnake.Member, time: str , reason: str):
                time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(time))
                await member.timeout(reason=reason, until=time)
                cool_time = disnake.utils.format_dt(time, style='R')
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    title=f"<:check:1085963560083013652>| Успешно",
                    description=f"Пользователь ``{member}`` был **замучен**\nмодератором {interaction.author.mention}\n<:3914279_1:1085952829413408889> **Причина** \n```{reason}```\n Мут исчезнет {cool_time}",
                    color=settings['color']
                                      )
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
````